# Compare images in node.js (using e.g. opencv)

Tags: javascript, node.js, opencv, image-processing, imagemagick

What I want to do is to get an image diff using node.js.
Ultimately I want to have a method expecting e.g. two filepaths or image data outputting the subtraction of both. Somehow like the [compare](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/compare.php) function in [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/).

Something like:

```
var comparison_result = compareModule.compare('./image1.png', './image2.png');
```

Also, I would like to get the position of the spots in the resulting image that mark the differences.

Like this:

```
comparison_result.forEach(function(difference) {
    console.log("A difference occurred at " + difference.x + "|" + difference.y);
});
```

I installed [node-opencv](https://github.com/peterbraden/node-opencv), however I can not find a documentation that maps basic opencv c++ functions to node.js.
The function I would like to use is [cvSub](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#subtract).

I would like to avoid [js-imagediff](https://github.com/HumbleSoftware/js-imagediff) as it works with canvas, has a dependency to "cairo" and I am not sure whether I can access the spots because in the documentation it rather seems like it just returns the difference as an image.

Comment: subtraction will give you another (difference) image. you're probably looking for something like a [norm](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#norm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never tried to calculate per-element difference by [`cv::addWeighted()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#addweighted) but it may work in practice:

```
var diff = new cv.Matrix(first.width(), first.height());
diff.addWeighted(first, 1.0, second, -1.0);
```

In native code (C++), this function can be replaced with the expression below:

```
diff = first*1.0 + second*(-1.0) + 0.0;
```

---

p.s.: node-opencv's authors published a sample code for measuring similarity:
[node-opencv / examples / dissimilarity.js](https://github.com/peterbraden/node-opencv/blob/master/examples/dissimilarity.js)

Comment: Really good answer! Your provided code worked instantly.
I haven't had the chance to build the newest version of the lib in order to test whether "cv.ImageSimilarity" would have also worked. However, I guess the function only returns a float value indicating the similarity of two images.
Next step for me will be clustering connected pixels so that two "pixel neighbours" are considered as one difference. That should be possible with https://github.com/peterbraden/node-opencv/blob/master/examples/detect-shapes.js